# why [ ] notation is used to input element to static array

Tags: php, static

in the original example `$methods` is a static array.It is used to assign outsider functions as methods to a class.But to input new element to this array writer used the following expression

```
static protected $methods = array();
```

i removed the static keyword from the variable declaration and tried to execute the code.

```
protected  $methods = array();
```

the execution gave the following error:

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Dynamic::$methods
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\json.php on line 6

***what is this [ ] notation is used for and how it is related to static keyword??***

original full code:

```
class Dynamic {
  static protected $methods = array();

  public static function registerMethod($method) {
    self::$methods[] = $method;
  }

  private function __call($method, $args) {
    if (in_array($method, self::$methods)) {
      return call_user_func_array($method, $args);
    }
  }
}

function test() {
  print "Hello World" . PHP_EOL;
}

Dynamic::registerMethod('test');
$d = new Dynamic();
$d->test();
```

Comment: When you removed `static` from definition of `$methods`, it can no longer be found by static `registerMethods`. That's what the error is about.

Comment: `[]` appends a new value onto an array (_any_ array - unrelated to static properties) (and creates the array if it doesn't exist) http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php  That is unrelated to your error - the error is because `self::$methods` refers to a static property, but having removed the `static` keyword from its declaration, you turned it into an instance property.

Comment: If you want to use it as an instance property instead of a static one, you'd need to use `$this->methods`, but that won't work inside the static method `registerMethod()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  but this array already declared.Then why i need to use [] notation ?

Comment: @al-Zami Look at the examples in the docs I linked. `[]` does not _declare_ an array (though it can), it _adds values onto_ an array. It being created if not already existing is a side effect.  It's like an alternative to `array_push()`, though possibly faster.

Comment: is it something similar to push method in javascript?

Comment: You need to read a PHP tutorial. Why would you remove the `static` keyword if you don't know what it does, and then be surprised that the program broke?

Comment: Yes, it is like the `.push()` method in JS, or `array_push()` in PHP.  http://codepad.viper-7.com/usvFwy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is this [ ] notation is used for and how it is related to static keyword??

The use of `static` and `[]` are unrelated.

The code `$array[] = $i` is a shorthand for pushing the element `$i` onto the end of the array `$array`. It could also be written `array_push($array, $i)`.